# limiting specializations using SFINAE, Constraints or Concepts?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, sfinae, c++-concepts, template-function

The following program runs fine:

```
struct M; // forward declare so compiler will recognize this type
struct N;

template< typename J > struct B { template< typename U > void Func1(); };

template<> template<> void B< M >::Func1< M >() {}
template<> template<> void B< N >::Func1< N >() {}
template<> template<> void B< M >::Func1< N >() {} // illegal specialization for this app

template< typename J > struct C { template< typename U > void Func2(); };

template<> template<> void C< M >::Func2< M >() {}
template<> template<> void C< N >::Func2< N >() {}

template< typename G > struct H { G g; };

int main()
{
  H< B< M > > hbm;
  hbm.g.Func1< M >(); // ok
  hbm.g.Func1< N >(); // compiles and runs, but uses a semantically illegal specialization for this app

  H< B< N > > hbn;
  hbn.g.Func1< N >(); // ok

  H< C< M > > hcm;
  hcm.g.Func2< M >(); // ok

  H< C< N > > hcn;
  hcn.g.Func2< N >(); // ok

  return 0;
}
```

It is important that structs B and C be declared explicitly at compile time and that only those specializations that make sense to the app be allowed.

But as can be seen in the code above, it is possible for my downstream developers (some day!) would be able to create syntactically correct patterns that don't make sense semantically. In specific, the app only knows how to use types whose class and function types are equal. The rest are nonsensical.

This seems like a case for one of the new C++17+ capabilities like SFINAE, Constraints or Concepts. Although I am reading up on these, I don't have the judgement yet to make that choice. In cppreference under Alternatives, they suggest Concepts instead of SFINAE if the compiler is capable (I use VS2015).

What would be a good way to constrain typename J to be the same as typename U?

Comment: SFINAE is not new to C++. And constraints effectively are the same thing as concepts.

Comment: You realize that concepts are not part of C++ 17?

Comment: `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U,J>{}>` in a template parameter list should suffice

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki There is nowhere to put that, save the specializations themselves (although preferably in the form of an assertion, of course). But then, if the programmer would be careful enough to write an assertion then presumably they would be equally careful not to write incorrect specializations to begin with.

Comment: @LucDanton if you don't specialize on the second, defaulted template parameter, each specialization defaults it as well

Comment: Why do you even have a separate template parameter if they have to be the same type anyway?

Comment: "Why do you even have a separate template parameter if they have to be the same type anyway? T.C.": I couldn't figure it out. The .h declaration only introduces the information once though. I couldn't get around having to template the B and C classes, although in my reading I could see there were some specialization constructs that looked like <T::B> or <T::C>.

Comment: "You realize that concepts are not part of C++ 17? – SergeyA " Yes, I know, but I am reasonably confidant today that Microsoft has gone modern C++-centric so I don't mind putting the newer constructs in my 1.0 production code. Future syntax tweaks are doable, but future re-writes are not. These constructs in general have converted my sprawling, exponentially size-increasing and non-maintainable prototype code into easily maintainable code. Nice job ISO C++ guys.

Comment: @T.C. It is not necessary to duplicate template parameters as you suspected as is the case in the original code: `A< D, B< D > > a1;` and `A< E, C< E > > a2;`. The construct to use was ‘template templates’ which was pointed out by @skypjack in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512060).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template< typename J > struct B {     
    template<typename U>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, J>::value, void>::type
    Func1();
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efb499cf654f0f25

With concepts (not in standard in near(?) future) the same solution as above would look as below.

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/li4Uh5Q6ilpnlhcl

```
template <class T, class U> concept bool Same = std::is_same<T,U>::value;

template< typename J > struct B { 
    template< typename U > 
    requires Same<J, U>    
    void Func1(); 
};
```

Comment: No, you can't this way. defaulted template arguments are not part of function signature.

Comment: This is one of those [Machiavelli vs. Murphy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c4b584653b49af2) situations, up to everyone to decide if that's any help.

Comment: @SergeyA you mean I should "copy" J template parameter, as here: template< typename U, typename J2=J, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<J2, U>::value> >  ?

Comment: @marcinj, I need to take it back. You are not going to create another overload of `Func1` within `B`, you simply disable the single Func1. Your code is OK.

Comment: [Another example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b18afe8af5019c9) that’s maybe more Murphy and less Machiavelli, where a potentially misguided programmer specializes the whole class template before the function template.

Comment: For slightly more defense against Machiavelli, put the `enable_if` in the return type.

Comment: @marcinj Your template solution compiles and runs using VS2015 Update 2, but your Concepts solution will have to go in the code as a comment until VS2015 implements Concepts.