# for a templated class with two templated variable, can one var be made to reference the other var?

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking for a way to reference A's t from within real types B and C. In the code below you see that my first inclination is to try and initialize it. Other attempts I have tried were using perfect forwarding, inheritance and adding more templates parameters to B and C. Can someone suggest a path forward? Are there new constructs on the way that may help? Am I close or is this impossible?

```
struct D {};
struct E {};

template< typename U1 > 
struct B 
{
  B() : u1(???)
  U1& u1; // how to reference A's t variable?
};

template< typename U2 > 
struct C 
{ 
  C() : u2(???)
  U2& u2; // how to reference A's t variable?
};

template< typename T, typename U >
struct A
{
  T t;
  U u;
};

int main()
{
  A< D, B< D > > a1;

  A< E, C< E > > a2;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: its is not clear what you want to achieve. Why does your template take two parameters if anyhow one is a reference to the other type?

Comment: actually I misread the title, but I still don't get what you want to do

Comment: This looks lile a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would really help if you would tell us what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the OP wants is a template template parameter.
Here is his code once reviewed:

```
#include<memory>

struct D {};
struct E {};

template< typename U > 
struct B 
{
    B(std::shared_ptr<U> v) : u{v} {}
    std::shared_ptr<U> u;
};

template< typename U > 
struct C 
{ 
    C(std::shared_ptr<U> v) : u{v} {}
    std::shared_ptr<U> u;
};

template< typename T, template<typename> typename U >
struct A
{
    A(): t{std::make_shared<T>()}, u{t} {}
    std::shared_ptr<T> t;
    U<T> u;
};

int main()
{
    A< D, B > a1;
    A< E, C > a2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. My apologies for you having to interpret my bad title and text, but really did want some suggestions as to how to move forward and template templates opened the door. Before I mark your code as the answer, though, can it be made to be a true reference of A's t? As it is, A's u and B's u are two separate u's despite the U& u. Would making the U a (shared?) pointer solve that?

Comment: @rtischer8277 Updated the example with a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: one cosmetic change is needed which was discovered while replacing the analytic with the semantic variables names. Currently calls look like: a1.t->... and a1.u.u->... . The second u, however, is actually t and is the same smart pointer as t since that is what the template template is being initialized with. Replacing both B and C's U and u and v's with T and t, alters the naming so that the desired call can be made: a1.u.t->... .